# Currently experiencing frequent DeadlineExceededExceptions when it was fine a few hours ago

Tags: google-app-engine

Is anyone else experiencing this? My app ID is chesspresso-service and since the early hours of this morning it's been hitting these over and over again..

```
2013-09-15 09:15:08.976
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@194d72e{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~chesspresso-service/8.370218489431632893}
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (2dd156b0a6c4d17b) started at 2013/09/15 06:14:08.061 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/15 06:15:07.583 UTC.
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:227)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:156)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:963)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$900(URLClassPath.java:752)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:897)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:890)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpenSynchronized(URLClassPath.java:889)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:881)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:817)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:774)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:423)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:407)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:406)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:382)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:208)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.UserClassLoader.findResource(UserClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1141)
    at org.mortbay.resource.Resource.newSystemResource(Resource.java:203)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureDefaults(WebXmlConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
C2013-09-15 09:15:08.993
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
I2013-09-15 09:15:09.430
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W2013-09-15 09:15:09.430
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)
```